# Trying to use the CSSMinify class in .NET

Tags: css, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Does anyone know how to use the .net cssminify class?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195101.aspx

Microsofts documentation is terrible (as with anything microsoft) and i tried googling example but can't find any. Has anyone every implemented this and can show some examples of how to do so? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to do? The CssMinify class is meant to be used as part of the bundling code. If you just want to perform CSS minification there may be better ways of doing it than trying to adapt the CssMinify class to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is CSS minification you're after just use Mvc's built in bundling.

Here is a link with a tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

You just need to add this and by default it will be minified.

```
bundles.Add(
new StyleBundle("~/Content/Bundle").Include(
"~/Content/CSS/your.css"));
```

**Update**

As mentioned by @selanac82, you could also add the below as a transform.

```
cssbundle.Transform.Add(new CssMinify());
```

Comment: thanks. this was very helpful. for those who want a quick answer in the future all i had to do was add a new instance of cssminify as a transform. so for me i added this line to my code

cssbundle.Transform.Add(new CssMinify());

and that did the trick. I was pointed that way in the article mentioned in this answer. Thanks @hutchonoid

Comment: the comment is more useful than the answer. I was missing the `.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());`

Comment: @Liam Thanks, I have added that to the answer to help other's find it.

Comment: @Liam I'll have a look. It usually only gets minified in release mode by default. It's not that is it, that confused me to begin with.

Comment: Got it, it was firebug messing with the output